# NiFi: Increase the size of a single flowfile

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using `NiFi 1.8` version and my flow has `ConsumeKafkaRecord` and then has a `wait processor` right after that. 
The problem Im seeing here is just for 20MB it creates `10000 flowfiles` which is the limit for now and 
the queue is stuck for sometime and expires after `Expiration parameter`. 
How do I `increase the size of a single flowfile` so I dont hit `10000` and stuck in the queue?
Or is there a better way of designing this?

Any suggestions/recommendations would be much appreciated.

Here are the configurations:
[image]

[image]

Comment: increase the queue size.

Comment: I have already increased queue size and that's how it works now. But would like to know if it's possible to increase the flowfile size.

Comment: what do you mean by "increase flow file size"? do you want to merge several flow files into one?